# HitTesting in javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, hittest

I am looking for a function/plugin in javascript or JQuery to test if two images hit each other. The one image moves around, the other one doesn't. The hard thing is, it should account for transparancy in the images.

So far, I have tried using [this plugin](https://github.com/e-smartdev/smartJQueryHitTest) for JQuery, but it keeps returning an error (something with a function insde the plugin itself). I can also write my own hitTest-function, but the problem is that I have no idea how to look for transparancy using javascript.

Comment: So what you're saying is that you'd like some plugin written in javascript that will be aware of transparency in your images and check if whatever parts of your images are'nt transparent does not collide? Afaik, that's not possible, unless you're using some seriously advanced crap with canvas etc. and as far as I know there are no plugins that do what you are asking for.

Comment: the plugin provided in my question should do what I need, but it keeps throwing errors -.-